# JQuery Validate remote with progress Indicator

Tags: jquery, validation

Is it possible to show a progress indicator for Jquery Validator remote? Essentially I need to handle beforeSend and complete events of the Ajax request made by the remote validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. You can just use Ajax options (beforeSend, complete etc):

```
   accountname: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    onkeyup: false,
                    url: '/register/if-account-exists',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        username: function () {
                            return $('#accountName').val()
                        }
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        console.info('before send')
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        console.info('complete')
                    }
                }
            }
```